# Reversed Running Total DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculation, ssas-tabular

I have two tables:

```
Transactions:
CalendarID
LoanID
Amount

Calendar:
CalendarID
Date
Month
Quarter
Year
```

And I need to calculate the 'outstanding' that is the reversed running total of the transactions table as a measure for a Power BI report.

Dependent on what kind of filter, I need to sum all future payments for each LoanID, without the current period. That is if my filter is based on quarter and I select Q3 2020, then I need the following result:

```
Q4 2020 + Q1 2021 + Q2 2021 + Q3 2021 + ...
```

Hope this makes sense, and that you can help me :-)

Working with my data model in Visual Studio 2017, it is tabular.

*** UPDATE ***

I made it work this way:

```
Outstanding:= 

VAR varEndOfQ= MAX(_TransactionDateCalendar[CalendarID])    

RETURN
CALCULATE([Repayments] ,FILTER(ALLSELECTED(_TransactionDateCalendar) ,
_TransactionDateCalendar[CalendarID] > varEndOfQ) )
```

But a problem I have now, is that each row is attached to a Loan, which has an effective date. And I don't want to show the loans in the graph before they are effective. That is before we actually start repaying the loans, they just have the same amount outstanding from the earliest date in the calendar dimension.

I've tried solving it like this:

```
Outstanding:= 

VAR varEndOfQ= MAX(_TransactionDateCalendar[CalendarID])
VAR varStartOfQ= MIN(_TransactionDateCalendar[CalendarID])

RETURN
CALCULATE([Repayments] ,FILTER(ALLSELECTED(_TransactionDateCalendar) , 
_TransactionDateCalendar[CalendarID] > varEndOfQ) , 
FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Fact_LoanFacility) , 
Fact_LoanFacility[EffectiveDateID] >= varStartOfQ))
```

But then it can't divide the transaction amounts over the loans, they all just have the same amount ...

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a solution:

```
Outstanding:=

VAR varEndOfQ= MAX(_TransactionDateCalendar[CalendarID])
VAR varStartOfQ= MIN(_TransactionDateCalendar[CalendarID])

RETURN

CALCULATE([Repayments] 
, FILTER(ALL(_TransactionDateCalendar) , _TransactionDateCalendar[CalendarID] > varEndOfQ)
, FILTER(Fact_LoanFacility, Fact_LoanFacility[EffectiveDateID] < varStartOfQ))
```